# In LESS, how to rewrite this CSS composition style?

Tags: html, css, less

Here is my CSS snippet:

```
div.header {
  border: 1px solid #842210;
}
div.header#id {
  position: relative;
}
```

I thought the following LESS codes may work, but actually it didn't:

```
@border-width: 1px;
@red: #842210;
div.header {
    #id {
    position: relative;
  }
    border: @border-width solid @red;
}
```

Does anyone have ideas about how to rewrite the CSS code with LESS?

Comment: Just add the parent selector `&` before `#id` :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you have it, you will select `div.header #id` instead of `div.header#id`. You can fix that with a [parent selector](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature) (&):

```
div.header {

  &#id {
    position: relative;
  }

  border: @border-width solid @red;

}
```